# How to create folder in test lab in quality center using perl

Tags: perl

Is there any way to create the folder and/or test sets in Test Lab in quality center using Perl?

Answer (score 0):

mkdir command=Makes a folder with the name and path EXPR using the mode specified by MODE, which should be supplied as an octal value for clarity.
example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$dirname ="/tmp/testdir";

mkdir $dirname, 0755;
```

Comment: It is not MODE, it is MASK, as modified by "umask".